# ld: framework not found SDL2_image

Tags: c++, frameworks, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-image

I want to use  `SDL2_image frameworks`  (an extension of SDL2 framework), i've downloaded and copied the `SDL2_image frameworks`  in the folders below:

> /Library/Frameworks/
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks
>
> /Users/ < user > /Library/Frameworks

my code works fine with SDL2 framework but when i add SDL2_image framework i get an error as follows:

```
ld: framework not found SDL2_image
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i tried clearing my framework search path, tried to change my valid architecture section none of them has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the `Base SDK` option to `Current OS X` for both the Target and Modules

Instructions are as follows:

> > from project navigator select your project -> Select build Settings -> from architectures field change **Base SDK** to **Current OS X**.